# Change Form.Select menu behavior to overflow scroll in react-bootstrap

Tags: react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-form

I have a modal that has a Form.Select input with some game names. Whats I want to do is make the menu show only 5 items and when it has more than 5, enable the scroll in the menu.

I already tried set overflow: scroll and set a fixed height, but got no results.

[Form.Select code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOsNs.png)

The current behavior is this one:

[Form.Select behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBzDN.png)

No matter how many items I have in my list, it never changes to scroll.